# Using FirebaseUI with URLEmbeddedView - Populate Cells with fetched Data

Tags: swift, github, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to populate cells with data, coming from 2 sources.
The first is a URL coming from the firebase database. This part works.

Then I'm using [URLEmbeddedView](https://github.com/szk-atmosphere/URLEmbeddedView) to scrap the page title from this page behind the URL, and then I also want to put this page title in the the `customCell`, next to the URL from firebase. This part doesn't work so far, I'm able to scrap data for a "constant" URL (i.e. when I set it to "google.com"), but the crucial part is how do I repeat this step for every URL it fetches from firebase?

```
dataSource?.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in

            let customCell = cell as! CustomCellTableViewCell
            let snap = obj as! FIRDataSnapshot

            let childString = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]

            let url = childString["url"] as? String
            let urlString = String(url!)
            let constantURL = "https://google.com/" 

//If a single URL is used, it works, but not for urlString above
            OGDataProvider.sharedInstance.fetchOGData(urlString: urlString) { [weak self] ogData, error in
                if let _ = error {
                    return
                }

            let pageTitle = ogData.pageTitle

            customCell.titleLabel.text = pageTitle
            customCell.urlLabel.text = String(url!)

            }

       tableView.dataSource = dataSource
       tableView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

I hope it's possible to understand my issue.